# problemas con tryCatch

Tags: r

Buenas, tengo un código en el que por medio de un bucle se van abriendo y analizando archivos que figuran en una lista. 
Como voy a tener que analizar varios archivos quiero que se imprima el nombre del archivo que tiene problemas para abrir. Un problema que es común que tengan los archivos es que falte algún nombre de columna, por ejemplo en vez de tener:

```
ID; date; close; description
1;20-12-2017;0.5;"archivo"
```

tiene

```
ID; close; description
1;20-12-2017;0.5;"archivo"
```

Esto evidentemente levanta un error ya que al leer el archivo se ve que el número de nombres de columnas no se corresponde con el número de columnas.

Para detectar estos errores estoy siguiendo el siguiente código:

```
  for (i in 1:length(files)){
    tryCatch({
    name<-as.character(files[i])
    dat<-read.table(name,header = T,sep="@",dec=",",comment.char = "")
    },
    error<-function(e){
    print("error in file",files[i])
    })
```

donde files es un listado de archivos.

Entonces lo que intento es que se imprima en pantalla el nombre del archivo.

El error que me salta es:

```
3.stop("bad handler specification") 
2.tryCatch({
    name <- as.character(files[i])
    dat <- read.table(name, header = T, sep = "@", dec = ",", 
        comment.char = "") ... 
1.data_function(files)
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahinoa, si el `tryCatch()` no está capturando el error, lo más probable que se trate de un `warning`, agrega también un manejador para estos:

```
files = c("archivo.txt", "archivo2.txt")
for (i in 1:length(files)){
    tryCatch({
        dat<-read.table(files[i], header = T,sep=";",dec=".")
    },
    warning = function(w) {
        print(paste("Warning:", w, "in file:", files[i]))
    },
    error<-function(e){
        print(paste("Error:", e, "in file:",files[i]))
    },
    finally = {
        print(paste("Fin del proceso de :", files[i]))
    }
    )
}
```

El vector `files` corresponde a dos archivos creados en función de tus dos ejemplo, el `archivo2.txt` le falta adrede un fin de linea al último registro. Revisa los parámetros de `read.table` por que no se corresponde con los archivos, el separador es `;` y los decimales se separan con `.`. Por otro lado te comento que los `print` están mal construidos, esto: `print("error in file",files[i])` no funciona o bien haces `print(c("error in file",files[i]))` o mucho mejor `print(paste("error in file",files[i]))`.

La ejecución arroja la siguiente salida:

```
[1] "Fin del proceso de : archivo.txt"
[1] "Warning: simpleWarning in read.table(files[i], header = T, sep = \";\", dec = \".\"): incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'archivo2.txt'\n in file: archivo2.txt"
[1] "Fin del proceso de : archivo2.txt"
```

Vemos que el segundo archivo genera un `warning` que es capturado por el `tryCatch()`

Comment: Lo he proado y ya no da el mismo error pero me salta este: `Error in read.table(name, header = T, sep = "@", dec = ",", comment.char = "",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed` es decir, que me lee la tabla y por la falta de una columna se toma la primera columan como nombre de fila, en la que hay duplicados y no la puede leer. A parte, hay un error, pero no me sale el mensaje de error con el archivo equivocado. No sé muy bien que pasa.

Comment: Ese problema lo resuelves usando el parámetro `row.names=NULL` de `ead.table`, de forma que simplemente te nombrará las filas con un número secuencial. De todas formas entiendo que te debería capturar el error. Dejame probarlo.

Comment: ya había puesto lo de `row.names=NULL` pero en vez de indices me crea la columna row.names, y ahí me mete los datos de la primera columna.

Comment: @Ahinoa, revisa también la sintaxis de `read.table` que no se corresponde con los ejemplos. Acabo de editar mi respuesta agregando algunos cambios a tu código original, el ejemplo me funciona tal como indico. Por las dudas mi versión de R es 3.4.3

Comment: @Ahino, te cuento además que el `read.table` tal como lo definiste en tu pregunta ni siquiera me da error, cosa lógica, por que mirando los ejemplos dónde el separador de campos es `;` si usas como separador el `@` lo que va a ocurrir es que simplemente cada linea sea una única columna, por consiguiente no vamos a tener ningún error o warning. Revisa el código y ejemplo de tu pregunta, por que al menos yo no puedo reproducirlo.